# How to align my div columns

Tags: html, css

My div columns look like the screenshot below. How can I align the columns so that they are the same height no matter the difference in content? With plain html/css alone or with the help of javascript/jquery/angularjs, but without bootstrap since I'm not allowed to use that framework.

Comment: `.pack {vertical-align: top;}` - not sure, but might help

Comment: This is a HTML and CSS question but your example is loaded with PHP and many of us can't or won't help you for that reason.

Comment: Sorry yes there is PHP to display the data but since it has nothing to do with the layout issue I thought it wasn't necessary to tag it as PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at `display:flex;`? I believe it does what you want:

```
.galeria_packs {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This should make each row the same height, even if there's more content in one of the boxes than the others.

Heres a (quick) working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7286jfd/), showing the result.

Comment: consider adding a small working code to show the result ;)

Answer (score 2):

By adding `display:flex` to the container, all the children items will be the same height.

But they will also all be in the same row.  To limit only 3 per row, like your mock above - add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the container. And make sure your items have a width.

```
.galeria_packs {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

See the jsfiddle with your provided code:
http://jsfiddle.net/yv363pcy/